# How to compare two models' MSE if the answer range differs?

Tags: error, model-comparison

I have two prediction models. The first one returns answers in the range 0 to 1, where the correct answer is 0 or 1. The second returns answers in the range -1 to 1, and the correct answer is -1 or 1.

I have the MSE for both modes, and I want to compare performance.

What is the correct way to do this? Simply divide the MSE of the second model by 4?

Comment: if -1 exactly corresponds to 0 in the other (and 1 exactly corresponds to 1), then yes.

Comment: Yes, -1 corresponds to 0 and 1 corresponds to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a model where you had predictions, $\hat {y}_A$ and $\hat {y}_B$ (for some models, $A$ and $B$), both on the same scale (say, the $[0,1]$ scale - I include the endpoints because I also want the discussion to include the correct answers ($y$) and because some kinds of models may well produce endpoint-values). Then you could directly compare mean square error (MSE).

These models may be nonlinear; all that we care about is fidelity of the predictions.

[I will leave aside considerations of whether that choice - MSE - is necessarily the best option, and assume that you do know what you want.]

Now consider that there's notionally a $y_B$, but you don't have $\hat {y}_B$; instead you have $\hat {v}_B = 2\hat {y}_B -1$, which is on the $[-1,1]$ scale, but is otherwise a similar problem. Then we can take the correct $v$ values back to $y$'s by $y=(v+1)/2$, and similarly for the $\hat {v}_B$ values. The MSE values would then (clearly) be the MSE for the $v$-values divided by 4.

[The question is, then, are MSE's for two different situations really comparable (such as given in the original problem of comparing $\hat {y}_A$ and $\hat {y}_B$)? It's not a question I can answer for you on the information given, but it's certainly one you should ponder if you haven't already done so. Should MSE's for different data sets be comparable? Are they equally difficult to predict?]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I'm pretty new at this. The data is the same except the correct answers are transformed as you wrote. The two prediction models are different, and I want to assess which is better. For one of the models I only have MSE and one pair of values for sensitivity and precision (rather than a complete ROC curve). The other model is at my disposal and I can measure it however I want (MSE, ROC curve etc').